# How can I stop dbt cloud from adding a 'limit' clause to my SQL query?

Tags: dbt

How can I get dbt to stop adding a 'limit' clause to my SQL query? This is my query:

```
'alter table "HEAP"."PPP_CONVERSION_PPP_LANDING_PAGE_VIEWED_" drop column "TARGET_TEXT";

select * from "HEAP"."PPP_CONVERSION_PPP_LANDING_PAGE_VIEWED_"'
```

BUT when I compile the query it's adding 'limit' 500:

```
alter table "HEAP"."PPP_CONVERSION_PPP_LANDING_PAGE_VIEWED_" drop column "TARGET_TEXT";

select * from "HEAP"."PPP_CONVERSION_PPP_LANDING_PAGE_VIEWED_"
limit 500
/* limit added automatically by dbt cloud */
```

Why on earth is it adding that?

Comment: The limit is added automatically when you preview data in the UI.  When you run your project, it won't add the limit.

Comment: TL;DR -- dbt only supports SELECT SQL statements. I did not see this anywhere in their docs, spent 10 hours and finally figured this out. Hope this helps save someone else time.

Comment: @clanham1022 This isn't relevant to the question you've asked.  The "right" way to run your DDL is with a pre-hook.

To your point, while this information may be hard to find in a doc, it simply doesn't make sense to run anything but DQL in a model. dbt's paradigm is model-focused.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard limit within the dbt cloud console. However, this code isn't materialized in deployed models.

There's limited use to viewing more than 500 results within the console.